# singular values of $A-\alpha I_n$ while $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have to prove that singular values of $A-\alpha I_n$ are $\sigma_i+\alpha$, while $\sigma_i$s are singular values of $A$ and $A$ is hermitian and positive definite matrix. Also we know that:
$$\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \dots \ge \sigma_n $$  and $\alpha \gt -\sigma_n$.
I know for hermitian matrices, eigenvalues and singular values are the same, but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric it has spectral decomposition $P \Lambda P^T$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the main diagonal, and with orthogonal $P$, i.e., $P^TP=I$, hence,
$$
A+\alpha I = P \Lambda P^T+\alpha P P^T=P(\Lambda+\alpha I)P^T
$$
hence the singular values of $A+\alpha I $ are $\sigma_i + \alpha$.

Comment: what can $\Lambda$ be? 
I didn't understand the last part. How did you conclude the singular values are those?

Comment: 1. Added explaination. $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$. 2. For symmetric matrix, the SVD equals the eigen-decomposition which is unique, hence by showing that $A+\alpha I$ can be decomposed into the form $UDV=PDP^T$, thus $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues\singularvalues.

Comment: Thanks, would you explain why  $P$ is orthogonal?

Comment: This is a well known Theorem. You can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Comment: thanks a lot, I know it's not a part of my question, but would you tell me how can I show that the $A+\alpha I$ is positive definite?

Comment: $A$ symmetric hence a positive semi definite, thus use definition $v^T(A+aI)v$ to show that it (positiveness) holds for $A+aI$ and becomes strict. If you need a detailed answer - please consider posting a new question.